# Google Chrome and remote kiosks

Tags: web-applications, google-chrome-extension, windows-7, windows-server-2012, kiosk-mode

This isn't necessarily a programming question so please advise if I should post this elsewhere.

I have developed a kiosk interface using php and html, this resides on a Windows 2012 Apache web server, the kiosk home page is accessible internally at following URL `MyDomain/kiosk`.

We have 5 physical kiosks in various locations around the building. These kiosks are PCs running Win 7 and Google Chrome - **with various extensions enabled**.

When setting up a new kiosk we do the following;

1. physically setup the PC
2. set the Chrome home page to `MyDomain/kiosk`
3. install the necessary extensions *(Virtual Keyboard and Inactivity Reset)*
4. set Chrome to open in '--kiosk' mode
5. add Chrome to the startup programs
6. done

My question must I manually install these extensions on each of the 5 kiosks, or is there a more efficient way of doing this? Is there any way to 'centralise' steps 3 and 4 above, rather than having to do this at every kiosk.

Can I for example install Chrome on the web server, add the necessary extensions, then 'point' the existing kiosks' home page to this instance of Chrome?

Is extension syncing a possibility?

I'd like to start of as I mean to go on because the number of kiosks will inevitably increase (20+). Does it not make more sense to have a 'centralised' instance of Chrome where we can add/remove extensions and have these changes reflect across all of the kiosks?

Perhaps there is a better way to approach this, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/signin.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment @rsanchez - could you elaborate please?

Comment: Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) is a better place for this since it's about setting up an environment. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the easiest way around this is to setup a Google user and sign in to the browser on each kiosk. This way all the extensions will sync.